# Android camera: get a straight picture on all devices

Tags: android, camera

So i got this simple app, open the camera (either front or back), take a picture, post it.

I managed to get a straight preview, despite the display orientation.

The problem is when I get the picture. If for example  I take a photo with different devices in portrait mode, the resulting pictures  are rotated of different angles, depending which device was used.

All I'm asking is simple: do you know how I can get straight pictures (either portrait or landscape, according to the rotation) and make sure it works on every device?

Well' if any of you has a solution,please share it,I'll be eternally grateful!

Comment: I suppose the user is taking a picture and you are not detecting the device orientation. I dont code android, but what you have to do is: detect device orientation. Parse data recieved and rotate  the image corresponding with the orientation

Answer (score 0):

Different devices use different orientations on their pictures by default. This can be annoying. What you need to do is find that orientation, and flip the image correspondingly.

Here's some code that I use in my application:
Note: I'm sure this isn't perfect. If anyone has suggestions on how to improve this, please feel free to comment/edit!

```
private int getOrientation(String pathToYourImage) throws IOException{
    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(path);
    int rotation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

    if (rotation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90){
        return 90;
    } else if (rotation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180){
        return 180;
    } else if (rotation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270){
        return 270;
    }
    return 0;       
}
```

then something like

```
if (orientation > 0){
    originalImage = rotateBitmap(originalImage, orientation);
}

private Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap srcBitmap, int angle){
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(srcBitmap, 0, 0, srcBitmap.getWidth(), srcBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    srcBitmap.recycle();
    return rotatedBitmap;
}
```

This might not completely suit your needs, but it works well enough for me. Ask if you have any more questions!